# How to display WIRIS formula without the Editor

Tags: rich-text-editor, wiris

I am using WIRIS in my website to add questions to database. I need to display the question on the on the website without the editor.
I have retrieved the question from the database but unable to get the styling right. Instead, the question only displays numbers instead o a well formatted formula.

Is there a way to get the equations styled without the editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `<script src="https://www.wiris.net/demo/plugins/app/WIRISplugins.js?viewer=image"></script>` to your html page's head tag and it will render your MathML formula as image.

Please refer documentation provided by wiris
https://docs.wiris.com/en/mathtype/mathtype_web/integrations/mathml-mode